# eventmachine memcache and heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, memcached, eventmachine, goliath

I'm trying to use the eventmachine built in memcache client (with em-synchrony) in my goliath powered web app. It runs beautifully locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, I can't get it to connect. Here's what I'm using to open the connection:

```
cache = EM::P::Memcache.connect
```

Is there a way I can get it to work, or am I going to have to use a different client, like Dalli? Are there any other eventmachine based memcache clients? Cheers for any help

Comment: You do have this add-on configured, correct? https://addons.heroku.com/memcache

Comment: Yeah it was configured correctly. I discovered that heroku needs SASL authentication, which the EM memcache client doesn't have. It turns out Dalli (which does support it) actually has an async mode that works beautifully

Comment: ahh I see, you should post that as the answer for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the EventMachine memcache client doesn't support SASL authentication, which heroku (and some other hosted memcache servers) require. I was initially avoiding the Dalli gem because I thought it lacked async support, but you just have to set `async => true` when instantiating the client and it works great

Comment: While the above answer is correct, you should be aware that `async` option support has been removed from Dalli as of version 2.0 - see [History](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/History.md). So the latest version this option works is 1.1.5